# How do I stop a video once I close the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, modal-dialog

I am very new to bootstrap and am trying to make my video sound stop playing when I click out of the modal.

I have looked on similar threads and tried the solutions but none seem to be working for me.

I know there must be a jQuery solution somewhere! I also want it to apply to everything in the class 'portfolio-modal modal fade'.

There are also two ways of closing - the X in the top right corner and the button underneath the video. Does this make a difference?

Thank you!

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Growing, Custo by LIDL</h2>
                        <p class="item-intro text-muted">Music Production for Growing, Custo.</p>
                        <iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/knjuAUOWgas" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <p>Description</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on close the window load the iframe again document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();

Comment: may be this help https://jsfiddle.net/xu40sp05/

Comment: @Shehary actually, got it working! thank you